# How to generate leters insted of number in pandas multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have multiindex table in pandas and I need to generate some string values instead of numbers. I need `data` to generate letters from a to z, and to be random. How do I do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2020], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                                   names=['year', 'q'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Items1', 'Items2', 'Items3'], ['new', 'old']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])

data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 6), 1)
data[:, ::2] *= 20
data += 50

Ldata = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

Ldata
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

```
data = np.random.seed(123)
data = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), (4,6)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).